# Dayforce APIs and Talend

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, talend

I am trying to use dayforce's APIs within Talend to pull data from a report.

The way it works is that I need to first acquire the Client and then Authenticate and then Call the Report Names with the Code.

I am stuck on acquiring the client. The WSDL URL takes in a parameter and returns the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
<root>
<row>
<check>&lt;ns1:GetClientSiteUriResult xmlns:a=&quot;http://Dayforce/Services/Data&quot; xmlns:i=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&quot; xmlns:ns1=&quot;http://Dayforce/Services/DayforceService&quot;&gt;&lt;a:Error&gt;&lt;a:Code&gt;0&lt;/a:Code&gt;&lt;a:Message i:nil=&quot;true&quot;/&gt;&lt;a:StackTrace i:nil=&quot;true&quot;/&gt;&lt;/a:Error&gt;&lt;a:ServiceVersion&gt;49.0.16090.6&lt;/a:ServiceVersion&gt;&lt;a:Uri&gt;https://748.dayforcehcm.com/Datasvc/DayforceService.svc&lt;/a:Uri&gt;&lt;/ns1:GetClientSiteUriResult&gt;</check>
</row>
</root>
```

How do I extract the URI from this response? The URI is https://748.dayforcehcm.com/Datasvc/DayforceService.svc

How do I use the URI from there to call the Authenticate API method. The Authenticate only accepts 3 parameters the company name, the user and the password. How would I use the URI?

```
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3578
[statistics] connected
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation
    Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement

    at dayforce_apis.dayforce_employee_listing_0_1.Dayforce_Employee_Listing.tSOAP_1Process(Dayforce_Employee_Listing.java:330)
    at dayforce_apis.dayforce_employee_listing_0_1.Dayforce_Employee_Listing.runJobInTOS(Dayforce_Employee_Listing.java:610)
    at dayforce_apis.dayforce_employee_listing_0_1.Dayforce_Employee_Listing.main(Dayforce_Employee_Listing.java:467)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing something wrong, but your message doesn't explain well enough how you are having your output message.

First, which version of Talend are you using ? TOS or subscription studio ? which exact version ? 5.6, 6.0, 6.1, 6.2 ?

Second, you have to put at least a picture of your job. There are multiple components to query a SOAP web service:

- tWebService (available in Open Source version): parses WSDL file and XSDs to map talend columns to XML documents
- tSOAP (available in Open Source version): provides less features, but gives the user more freedom to generate XML input and parse output.
- tESBConsumer (only available in subscription version): provides equivalent features to tWebService + support of Security and Infrastructure Talend components.

I would suggest using tSOAP, which offers the most freedom in this case.
You can find information about the component and a couple of use cases here : 
[tSOAP Documentation](https://help.talend.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=268971068)

Here is a Job screenshot:
[image: tSOAP Job screenshot]

In order to get to this result, you have to:

- Use SOAP UI (or any other SOAP client) to import WSDL and try a request
- Copy the input message inside the tSOAP component, don't forget to check "Output as Document" in tSOAP. Your tSOAP component should look similar to this :

[image: tSOAP component view]

- Create an XML file with the output structure from SOAP UI
- import the XML structure in tXMLMap component using the import structure function as shown hereafter:

[image: tXMLMap import structure]

- Map the needed elements to your tXMLMap output

[image: tXMLMap mappings]

It is not absolutely necessary in this case to use tXMLMap, if you have more experience with XPath, you can try tExtractXMLField component.

Comment: Thank you that was extremely helpful. Can I please see what your component screenshot looks like. I am not sure what the EndPoint should be. What is the URL that you are using for the EndPoint and Soap Action?

Comment: The answer was updated with an additional screen in the tSOAP part.

Comment: My component looks exactly the same, but I get an error.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation
 Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement

Comment: Take a look at your XML message. it has double quotes for sure. you have to escape the double-quotes with \ , or remove the namespaces. You can take a closer look at my configuration, the double-quotes inside the message are \" .

Comment: That was exactly it. Thanks

Comment: I am completely lost at the following point: Create an XML file with the output structure from SOAP UI
import the XML structure in tXMLMap component using the import structure function as shown hereafter:

Does that mean I take the XML i copied earlier, save that to an XML file in  folder locally, and then in the XMLTMap, import the file. If that is what you are suggesting. I tried this but I am not table to see the code, Servic eVersion, etc.

Comment: @how do you get the structure of Client URI from the WSDL?

Comment: @a415 for the XML Schema it should work the way you described in your commend. For your last comment, I am not sure to understand well, but it seems you would like to get the structure of the request for a specific SOAP operation. In order to do that, it is a bit more complicated, you have to create a Web Service in the repository (only available in ESB versions) and import your WSDL, then right-click on the Web Service operation and generate XML Schema.